# Откуда берется интернет?

Tags: трафик

Понимаю, что вопрос тупой, но все же, он меня мучает.Что такое интернет я понимаю. Мне непонятен один ньюанс лишь:

Есть провайдеры, которые продают трафик, откуда они его берут?Я знаю одного провайдера (мой знакомый), он берет и покупает "оптом" трафик у другого провайдера, бьет на более мелкую ширину канала и продает сам, как провайдер.

Ок, допустим, подавляющее большинство провайдеров (наверное) берут также трафик у кого-то другого, а откуда берет трафик этот "кто-то другой" ?

Возможно, вопрос мой совсем идиотский, скажите хоть что гуглить.Спасибо.

Comment: Для начала [интернет][1].  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82

Comment: Спасибо за информацию Очень полезна .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Из [*точек обмена трафиком*](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%EE%F7%EA%E0_%EE%E1%EC%E5%ED%E0_%E8%ED%F2%E5%F0%ED%E5%F2-%F2%F0%E0%F4%E8%EA%EE%EC).
- А также почитайте про [*пиринг*](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)

Answer (score 1):

Я вот по этим ссылкам не ходил (что дали свыше). Но как бы там оно ни было, интернет - это соединение (объединение) всех компьютеров в мире в одну глобальную сеть при помощи проводов или же без оных (к чему сейчас большинство стремится). Напр., захотел я с соседом соединить наши ПК, соединили. Пришел еще один сосед сказал: - Я тож хочу, возьмите меня к себе? А мы ему, допустим - 5 руб. в день плати и будешь в нашей ко. Вот так оно и завертелось (я думаю, не стоит описывать все, что происходило при 1-ых зачатках, об этом можно, действительно, в статьях почитать).

Comment: Интернет - объединение компьютерных сетей, но не компьютеров.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос.Аналог - а откуда берётся воздух? или вода?Или почему дует ветер :)Но всё же есть, над чем подумать.Вот он! Великий! И могучий!см. [его схема](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Internet_map_1024.jpg?uselang=ru)

Это как вода, которую гоняют по трубам, из больших в маленькие, из маленьких в большие.
Ведь вода автономна, так и интернет, у него нет прямого источника (как у нефтяной скважины). Он как-бы аморфен (я про трафик). Трафик это движение, поток.
А ресурсы люди сами делают. Картинки, фильмы, сайты и прочее и прочее...
И так продолжается аж с прошлого тысячелетия :)

Answer (score -3):

Ну для начала, уважаемый, вам бы надо выстроить локальную сеточку с хорошими мощностями. Т.е. коммутационным оборудованием с хорошей пропускной способностью, небольшим серверочком / серверочками (внимание! не на основе домашнего PC!) для управления сей сеткой, поднять несколько DNS-ов, что-нибудь для авторизации (radius там, ну или  AD - если деньга позволит), хорошим запасом места на системах хранения данных (внимание, не винчестером SATA на 2Т!) и т.д. и т.п. Выйдет как минимум в стойку. Учтите, что сетка должна быть не в пределах одной комнаты/дома, а "многосекторная", где сектора будут объединяться как минимум парой каналов (резервный и основной). Вобщем, железо, железо и железо. После этого открываетесь как ООО (например) ну или ЗАО. И идёте потом в MSK-IX (мских) с предложением, мол, "я такой вот крутой и замечательный, построил небольшую локальную сеточку с несколькими независимыми секторами, объединил ей на первое время квартал в своём родном городе (посёлке/деревне) и вот уж очень хочу стать провайдером, пустите меня, пожалуйста, в свой сладкий круг". Уважаемая мских рассмотрит ваше предложение и если вы действительно сделаете всё указанное - то как минимум предложит вам для начала обратиться к своему дочернему IX. Ну а если у вас хорошее покрытие - то может и сразу вас в свои "дочки" принять. Тут уже документы-документы-документы. Ну а потом вы уж и сами знаете что делать ;)

Comment: Ну и за что минус? Жду комментария, а необоснованный минус поставить - ума много не надо ;)

Comment: Ну я думаю, минуса за то, что на такой вопрос надо было отвечать по-простому .